# Hive Joins query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-hive

I have two tables in hive: 
Table 1:

```
1,Nail,maher,24,6.2
2,finn,egan,23,5.9
3,Hadm,Sha,28,6.0
4,bob,hope,55,7.2
```

Table 2 :

```
1,Nail,maher,24,6.2
2,finn,egan,23,5.9
3,Hadm,Sha,28,6.0
4,bob,hope,55,7.2
5,john,hill,22,5.5
6,todger,hommy,11,2.2
7,jim,cnt,99,9.9
8,will,hats,43,11.2
```

Is there any way in Hive to retrieve the new data in table 2 that doesn't exist in table 1??

In other Databases tools, you would use a inner left/right. But **inner left/right** doesn't exist in Hive and suggestions how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hive version >= 0.13 you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.firstname, A.lastname ... IN (SELECT B.firstname, B.lastname ... FROM B);
```

But I'm not sure if Hive supports multiple coloumns in the IN clause.
If not something like this could work:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.firstname IN (SELECT B.firstname FROM B) AND A.lastname IN (SELECT b.lastname FROM B) ...;
```

Comment: That worked perfect all I had to do was use  **not in**.

FYI: the first one didn't work but the second one did. 

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be wiser to concatenate the fields together before testing for NOT IN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t2 
WHERE CONCAT(t2.firstname, t2.lastname, CAST(t2.val1 as STRING), CAST(t2.val2 as STRING)) NOT IN
    (SELECT CONCAT(t2.firstname, t2.lastname, CAST(t2.val1 as STRING), CAST(t2.val2 as STRING))
    FROM t1)
```

Performing sequential NOT IN sub-queries may give you erroneous results.

From the above example, a new record with the values ('nail','egan',28, 7.2) would not show up as new with sequential NOT IN statements.